# Understanding tuple-indexed measures and integrating them

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I have a measure $\mu $ that is supported on $[-3,3 ] \times \mathbb{R}$. What we are given is that, if we fix the first component $i$, then $\mu(i,\cdot)$ is a probability measure. Formally (maybe it should integrate to $\mathrm{d}i$ or similar, I cannot define this very well):
$$\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \mathrm{d}\mu(i,x) = 1 \quad \forall i \in [-3,3].$$
I find it very hard to understand this tuple-indexing notation. My question is the following: What kind of assumptions do we need to have a result similar to:
$$\int_{(i,x) \in [-3,3 ] \times \mathbb{R}} \mathrm{d} \mu(i,x) = \int_{i \in [-3,3]} \mathrm{d} i$$

I just think that since for any fixed $i$ the measure $\mu$ integrates to $1$ (on the second dimension -- apologies for my poor terminology), then integrating over all $(i,x) \in [-3,3 ] \times \mathbb{R}$ should also give simply an 'iterated integral' where we first integrate wrt $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for a fixed $i$, which will integrate to $1$ , and then integrate over $i \in [-3,3]$. But of course, we cannot define
$$\int_{(i,x) \in [-3,3 ] \times \mathbb{R}} \mathrm{d} \mu(i,x)= \color{red}{\int_{i \in
 [-3,3]} \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \mathrm{d} \mu(i,x) = \int_{i \in [-3,3]} \mathrm{d}y}$$
where in the red parts I make an abuse of integartion rules.

Answer (score 1):

The first equation you wrote, I think you probably mean $\mu(\{i\} \times \mathbb{R}) = 1$?

What you are trying to describe with iterated integrals might be the product measure and the Fubini/Tonelli theorems which allow you to convert an integral over a product measure $\nu_1 \times \nu_2$ to an iterated integral.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I mean that if you fix the first coordinate of $mu$ then this is a probability measure on the second coordinate. I cannot formalize this definition. Is there an easy way to write $\int_{[-3,3]\times \mathbb{R}} \mathrm{d} \mu(i,x)$ without defining a product measure?

Comment: I think also Fubini/Tonelli theorem holds if we had a density wrt the Lebesgue measure, but here I would like to keep things as general as possible.

Comment: $\int_{[-3, 3] \times \mathbb{R}}d\mu(i, x) = \mu([-3, 3] \times \mathbb{R})$ by definition.